# Retrieve surface values in hybrid sigma cordinate system

Tags: atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling

I need to retrieve surface values of a parameter in  high mountainous region that are in hybrid sigma coordinate system.

From what I have understood, hybrid sigma coordinate has three layers in the bottom there is pure sigma region which is able to capture the signature of the mountains at the very top of the atmosphere, pure hybrid sigma coordinate in the middle and Pure pressure region at the top.
[image: hybrid sigma coordinate]

So since the pure sigma region captures the signature of the mountain, does that mean the lower level values, in this figure (K+1/2) equals to surface values?

Comment: Yes; that's certainly the way it is in other atmospheric models with terrain-following model levels, so I certainly assume it's like that for you too!